# Only fire hover event when opacity of object is 1

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I've come across a bit of a problem with hovering over items when `opacity: 0;`, but because they still exist in the space (just not visible), unlike `display: none;`, any hover events attached to that object still happens.

Can't really post the code I'm using, but I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwDwj/1/) with a little more explanation to simulate it. Just as a note, I'd much rather not use any Javascript to solve it, try and keep it pure HTML/CSS. I've also posted the HTML and CSS from the fiddle below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="secondary-container">
        .opacity-0 fills this box.
        <div class="opacity-0"></div>
        <div class="on-hover">Hello, world!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.container .secondary-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .secondary-container .opacity-0 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -41px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.on-hover {
    display: none;
    color: white;
}

.container .secondary-container .opacity-0:hover ~ .on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

And the explanation:

Hover on the white square, and the text "Hello, world!" should display (from the div.on- hover). However, you are actually hovering over .opacity-0, as explicitly stated in the CSS.

I need to be able to hover over .opacity-0, and when the opacity is at 0 (i.e object is not visible, but still exists in the space), the hover event does not fire. When the opacity is at 1, and you hover over .opacity-0, the hover event carries on like normal. Preferably no Javascript should be used.

Hope that all makes sense, happy to answer any questions about it as I realise I may not have explained this amazingly well.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: So confusing...and this cannot be accomplished with CSS only

Comment: Would `pointer-events: none` be what you're looking for? Note that it doesn't work in IE or Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it :)  First, I need to say that I forgot to mention in the OP that I need the box to fade in with CSS3 transitions - sorry.

Using just `visibility:hidden;` did some weird stuff with the transition, so what I've done is use both visibility and opacity. This then transitions both but the visibility transition problems don't happen any more due to opacity apparently taking more preference. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you post the css you used? I have an object `#volume-holder{opacity:0}` and `#volume-holder:hover{opacity:1}` and it doesn't seem to work if the opacity is 0. If I set it to something like 0.1 then it works (I'm using chrome)

Answer (score 3):

try replacing `opacity:0;` with `visibility:hidden;`
http://jsfiddle.net/QwDwj/2/

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for your answer, I used it in part with another technique. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work. The hover-style will be used if you hover the element. Dont't forget that CSS isn't a programming language.

Why not using JavaScript for you needings ? I'm quite sure that jQuery has a fadeOut Method that sets the element at the end of the fade display:none.

Or you just use display:none and place your div into a div with fix height/width to keep your layout?

I can add a fiddle if you want me to.

Comment: I could use JS but I'd rather not, as its for quite an important feature of the site I'm building and if JS is disabled it will impair the user. I also forgot to mention that I preferably need the hover event to transition in and the display property doesn't allow transitions. Thank you for your help, I'll look into it :)

Comment: why display:none isn't an option ?

Comment: The display property doesn't allow transitions. From display: none; to display: block; it just appears, no fade in or anything. For a last resort I may have to use this but it definitely doesn't look as nice.